# Javascript Sweet Alert and using warning alerts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form button as follows:

```
<input type="button" value="Leave Room" id="disconnectLink" onclick="javascript:getConfirmation();" style="display: none" />
```

and getConfirmation() function as follows:

```
function getConfirmation(){
var retVal = confirm("Are you sure that you want to leave room?");
if( retVal == true ){
disconnect();   
return true;
}
```

which is working fine and correctly displaying alert. I need to add javascript sweetalert display:
https://www.ludu.co/lesson/how-to-use-sweetalert

I tried the following:

```
function getConfirmation(){
swal({
      title: "Are you sure?", 
      text: "Are you sure that you want to leave room?", 
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      closeOnConfirm: false,
      confirmButtonText: "Yes, leave room!",
      confirmButtonColor: "#ec6c62"
    }, function() {
disconnect();   
return true;
else{
return false;
}
}
})
```

But unfortunately it is not working and nothing happens on clicking Leave Room button.

What is going wrong with above code ??

Comment: Please refer to this link `[http://jsfiddle.net/hoja/5a6x3m36/5/]`

Comment: getConfirmation is not longer synchronous, so you can't return from it.

Comment: @Anand Choudhary Thank you so much ;)